# If they counter my Goblin Grenade, do I still lose my goblin?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If they use a [Counter Spell](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Counter%20Spell) or some other similar way to counter my [Goblin Grenade](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Goblin%20Grenade) do I still lose the sacrificed goblin?

Comment: Why would you expect to **not** lose the goblin?

Comment: @user1873: I think the OP was just confused about when costs are paid. (The original card text was a lot more confusing in that department, but given the gatherer links, it seems unlikely the OP was looking at that.)

Comment: @Jefromi, you are possibly correct. It might be the case that Yaztromo is an old 5th edition player. My familiarity with 5th edition rules isn't spectacular.

Comment: @user1873, to be honest, I'm originally an unlimited edition player... I always struggled to keep up with the game after the introduction of Ice Age as since then I played much much less than I used to...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. This is pretty obvious if you remember that, like the card says, sacrificing the goblin is *an additional cost*. It's like paying mana for a spell - and you don't get mana back if someone counters one of your spells.

If you want to read [the comp rules](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/TCG/Article.aspx?x=magic/rules), casting spells is section 601.1. Paying the cost for a spell is 601.2g; the spell becomes cast after that in 601.2h. At that point, it's on the stack and your opponent has a chance to counter it. When they do, the costs are already paid (your goblin is dead and your mana is spent).

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**. You pay costs to take actions. This includes Mana Costs listed right of the Card Name, and any additional costs within the cards Rules Text. Nothing in the Basic Rules allows you to get back costs that you paid to cast a spell. Remember, your opponent is paying a cost to counter your spell (usually a mana cost, and the instant counter spell that will leave their hand and go to their graveyard). It wouldn't be fair for them to have to pay to counter your spell, if you just got your resources back. From the [Basic Rulebook](http://media.wizards.com/images/magic/resources/rules/EN_MTGM13_Rulebook.pdf):

> **COST** - A cost is something you have to pay to take another action. You must pay a cost to cast a spell or activate an activated ability. Sometimes a spell or ability will also ask you to pay a cost when it resolves. You can’t pay a cost unless you can pay all of it.
>
> **COUNTER A SPELL OR ABILITY** - To cancel out a spell or ability so it has no effect. If a spell is countered, it’s removed from the stack and put into its owner’s graveyard.